# Azure DNS hostname or IP reference in web.config?

Tags: azure, web-config, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

When connecting to Azure services in my applications, is it preferable to use the DNS hostname or the IP?

For example, I have a SQL Server hosted in a virtual machine.  Should I configure my web.config with `168.63.xxx.xxx` or with `mysqlserver001.cloudapp.net`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `recommended` strategy.
While there is unofficial statement that the public IP address of a **deployed** cloud service (including Virtual Machine) will not change until it is completely deleted (all the VMs from the same cloud service are deleted, or the PaaS deployment is deleted), I would refrain from relying on it if I can. You can refer [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ryancrawcour/archive/2012/01/09/windows-azure-and-fixed-ip-addresses.aspx) and the links it refers for the dilemma of "fixed IP Address".

I would use DNS name. I would even use my own domain name, which is CNAME-d to the xxx.cloudapp.net domain.

Answer (score 1):

Both IP address and DNS name would work and are persistent as long as you don't delete the VM. But DNS name looks more friendly from my point of view.